# Fullcalendar problem with duplicate events

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar to save some events in a db, but after some tests I have made I saw a strange problem. Also I use bootstrap modal and axios from Vue to make request on Laravel.

So the problem is, for example when I click on date 5 and I remove modal does not add any data there, and after I close this modal I will reopen a new modal on date 8 without reloading windows and on date 8 I want to save some data, when I save for date 8 the event gets created twice, once for date 8 which is event I want and once for date 5 which is event I just clicked and open modal without saving data before.

How can I fix this?

```
//Modal is a bit longer so I will pass only fullcalendar function and data
import axios from 'axios'
import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom' // solves problem with Vite
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css'; 
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import bootstrap5Plugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap5'

export default {
    components: {
        FullCalendar
    },

    data() {
        return {
            ...
            calendarOptions: {
                plugins: [
                    dayGridPlugin, 
                    interactionPlugin,
                    timeGridPlugin,
                    listPlugin,
                    bootstrap5Plugin
                ],
                height: 650,
                eventColor: '#695CFE',
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
                },
                dateClick: this.handleDateClick,
                navLinks: true,
                dayMaxEvents: true,
                editable: false,
                selectable: true,
                weekends: false,
                droppable: false,
                allDay: true,
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
                select: this.selectEventFunction,
                eventSources: [
                    {
                        events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {

                            axios.get('/getDatas').then(response => {
                                successCallback(response.data.data)
                                // console.log(response.data.data)
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ],
                eventClick: this.removeEventfromCalendar,
            },
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        // Ajax X-CSRF-TOKEN
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    },

    methods: {

        selectEventFunction(selectionInfo) {
            $('#createEvent').off("click"); // Added off click there
            
            $('#addEventCalendar').modal('toggle');
            
            $('#createEvent').click(function () {
                var client_name = $('#chose_client').val();
                if (!client_name) {
                    var client_name = $('#client_name').val();
                }
                // console.log(client_name)
                var job_name = $('#job_name').val();
                var start_date = $('#eventStart').val();
                var end_date = $('#eventEnd').val();

                var template_name = $('#job_template').val();
                var job_type = $('#job_type').val();
                var job_description = $('#team_description').val();
                var duration = $('#jobDuration').val();
                var team_name = $('#assigne_team').val();
                var client_phone_number = $('#client_phone').val();
                var subject_type = $('#subject_type').val();
                var client_adress = $('#client_adress').val();
                // console.log(client_name)
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/jobs",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        job_name,
                        start_date,
                        end_date,
                        template_name,
                        job_type,
                        job_description,
                        duration,
                        team_name,
                        client_name,
                        client_phone_number,
                        subject_type,
                        client_adress,
                    },
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        // console.log(response)
                        Toastify({
                            text: response.success,
                            className: "info",
                            duration: 3000,
                            position: "right",
                            gravity: "top", 
                            close: true,
                            stopOnFocus: true,
                            style: {
                                background: "#695CFE",
                            }
                        }).showToast();
                        location.reload()
                    },
                    error:function(error)
                    {
                        // console.log(error)
                        Toastify({
                            text: error.responseJSON.errors.title,
                            className: "info",
                            duration: 3000,
                            position: "right",
                            gravity: "top", 
                            close: true,
                            stopOnFocus: true,
                            style: {
                                background: "#801427",
                            }
                        }).showToast();
                    },
                });
            });
        },

        //remove event from calendar
        removeEventfromCalendar(info)
        {
            info.el.style.borderColor = 'red'; //change clicked elemet border color
            var id = info.event.id;
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                axios.delete('/data/'+id, {
                    params: {
                        'id': id
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    Toastify({
                        text: error.response.data.message,
                        className: "info",
                        duration: 3000,
                        position: "right",
                        gravity: "top", 
                        close: true,
                        stopOnFocus: true,
                        style: {
                            background: "#801427",
                        }
                    }).showToast();
                })
                .then(response => {
                    Toastify({
                        text: response.data.success,
                        className: "info",
                        duration: 3000,
                        position: "right",
                        gravity: "top", 
                        close: true,
                        stopOnFocus: true,
                        style: {
                            background: "#695CFE",
                        }
                    }).showToast();
                    location.reload()
                })
                }
            })
        }
        // handleDateClick: function(arg) {
        //     alert('date click! ' + arg.dateStr)
        // },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#createEvent').click(function () {` is inside your `selectEventFunction`, so every time a selection is made and that callback runs, you're adding *another* "click" event handler to the same button. And you're not removing any of the previously-added ones from earlier selections. So then each time you click the button, *all* the attached event handlers will run.

So to resolve it you need to either move that handler outside the function, so it only runs once, or remove all previous event handlers on that button before adding a new one.

Comment: what exactly should i use to remove event.  I have checked the documentation and does now see any method how to remove event handler

Comment: @leoon0012 you need to use https://api.jquery.com/off/ . (You can also google "jquery remove event handler" if you need to find out something like this)

Comment: still does not understand what should i add on code. Can you do an example inmy case?

Comment: @leoon0012 Well did you try anything? Was there something in the documentation which you were unsure of? `$('#createEvent').off("click")` ought to do the trick. If not, mention it. (For clarity, you should add that line just before the `$('#createEvent').click(function () {` line).

Comment: Yes this do the trick. I set this .`off('click')` before `on('click')` function and it works

Comment: but there is a problem. Now `Toastify` and `location.reload()` does not work. Just updated the question to see changers i have made

Comment: Why do you want to reload the whole page anyway though? If you want to update the calendar, you could run the calendar's refetchEvents() function. in terms of Toastify, I don't know what "doesn't work" actually means. Do you see an error in the browser's console, for example? Have you verified that the Toastify command is even executed, using the JS debugger?

Comment: I want to see the calendar updates after i add an event but i dont know how to use `refetchEvent()` . And no i see no error on console

Comment: Have you verified that the Toastify command is even being executed then, as I mentioned? Use your debugger.

Comment: `i dont know how to use refetchEvent()`...well how about trying to find out? It's just a function, you just call it. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents . Because you're using the vueJS fullCalendar plugin, to get the `calendar` object, you need to follow the instructions in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue in the section called "Calendar API".

Comment: this work for `refetchEvent()`. But still have a problem. I can add an event successfully on db and can fetch using `refetchEvent()` but my function does not show success response but error response . i mean after i click submit on modal i see this result `error:function(error)
                    {
                        // console.log(error)
                        Toastify({
                            text: error.responseJSON.errors.title,` with an error con console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')`

Comment: `my function does not show success response but error response`...this probably indicates that either your server-side script crashed while it  was running, and/or it returned something that jQuery was unable to parse. I suggest debugging your server-side code, checking its error log, and examining the raw response from the server to your AJAX request by using your browser's Network tool.

Comment: I found the problem. I am using `DB::transactions` on laravel and have returned `json response` inside this `transactions` , just need to remove `jsonresponse `outside the `transactions ` now it works. Thank you